# perl regex exclude exact numbers between 1-50 and match

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Dear StackExchange Perl Regex Gurus,

Please how can I match all 2 to 6 digit numbers, but exclude numbers 0-50?
I am a complete neophyte in need of wisdom. This is for an apache mod_rewrite rule.

Comment: I'm not trying to match URLs, just number values found in those URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) site, you could use something like so: `^0*(5[1-9]|[6-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,5})$` to match numbers between 51 and 999,999.

A working example of the regular expression can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/qL8wB0/1).

Comment: Thank you, this really is a godsend.